# Automatically update xcore/ecore attribute

Tags: eclipse, attributes, emf, ecore, xcore

In an Eclipse plug-in I have a custom model defined in an `.xcore` file and it contains this `EClass` definition:

```
class Person {
    String name
    String surname

    Date dateUpdated
}
```

My question here is: if I manually edit any of the attributes of an instance of this class (in the Eclipse properties view), is there a way to automatically update the `dateUpdated` attribute?

I know that this can be done with an `EContentAdapter`, but is there an easier way to define this in the Xcore file or through some other mechanism?

Comment: Hi Dusan, this is Jens, I edited your question! Your can get really nice formatting on Stack Overwflow like this.